# How do I set medium weight font using TFontDialog?

Tags: delphi

Some fonts have only medium and bold weight. Given the code below do I have to avoid TFontDialog all together?
When choosing style medium from Dialog it returns weight 500 sets style BOLD. If I save this style and open TFontDialog back up its is now set to BOLD.

```
  FW_THIN = 100;
  {$EXTERNALSYM FW_EXTRALIGHT}
  FW_EXTRALIGHT = 200;
  {$EXTERNALSYM FW_LIGHT}
  FW_LIGHT = 300;
  {$EXTERNALSYM FW_NORMAL}
  FW_NORMAL = 400;
  {$EXTERNALSYM FW_MEDIUM}
  FW_MEDIUM = 500;
  {$EXTERNALSYM FW_SEMIBOLD}
  FW_SEMIBOLD = 600;
  {$EXTERNALSYM FW_BOLD}
  FW_BOLD = 700;
  {$EXTERNALSYM FW_EXTRABOLD}
  FW_EXTRABOLD = 800;
  {$EXTERNALSYM FW_HEAVY}
  FW_HEAVY = 900;

  {$EXTERNALSYM FW_REGULAR}
  FW_REGULAR = FW_NORMAL;

    procedure TFontDialog.UpdateFromLogFont(const LogFont: TLogFont);
     var
      Style: TFontStyles;
    begin
      with LogFont do
      begin
        Font.Name := LogFont.lfFaceName;
        Font.Height := LogFont.lfHeight;
        if FFontCharsetModified then
          Font.Charset := TFontCharset(LogFont.lfCharSet);
        Style := [];
        with LogFont do
        begin
          if lfWeight > FW_REGULAR then Include(Style, fsBold);
          if lfItalic <> 0 then Include(Style, fsItalic);
          if lfUnderline <> 0 then Include(Style, fsUnderline);
          if lfStrikeOut <> 0 then Include(Style, fsStrikeOut);
        end;
        Font.Style := Style;
      end;
    end;
```

Comment: According to that code, yes - TFontDialog won't work for you, because any font weight > FW_REGULAR merely adds `fsBold` to the `Font.Style`, and no other font weights are considered. This would mean that weights <= FW_REGULAR would not be bold, and > FW_REGULAR would be, with no other considerations.

Comment: Note that this is a limitation of `TFontDialog` itself, not the underlying Win32 `ChooseFont()` API.  The VCL has no concept of a "medium" style for fonts, a font is either bold or it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `TFontDialog` which is available from the VCL does not have any knowledge of this, nor does the `TFont` in Delphi. The VCL only acknowledges bold or not bold, no in-between font weights. You would have to bypass these altogether and implement your own dialog and font object(s) to accomplish such functionality.

Comment: You'd really need to skip TCanvas? I'd expect you could create your font, assign the handle to a TFont, and then go back to the VCL from there. Do TFont or TCanvas "normalize" the font to fit VCL font properties or something?

Comment: Indeed Rob, I expect to be able setting `Canvas.Font.Handle` to a by WinAPI gotten value. After that, as long as you don't alter the `Font` property, that handle will be used for drawing.

Comment: This is what I expected to hear, was just hoping for another solution. Haven't quite figured out how the "Font Style" options get filled out. Sometimes it has more choices available then the Font.Style would permit.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the TLogFont font info using this code in the OnClose event:

```
var
 LogFont: TLogFont;
begin
 if Sender is TFontDialog then
  with Sender as TFontDialog do
   SendGetStructMessage(Handle, WM_CHOOSEFONT_GETLOGFONT, 0, LogFont);
end;
```

The following units are needed: Windows, Messages and CommDlg.
I am still looking on how to set the TLogFont data to de dialog on show and how to use it with a TCanvas.